# unable to connect with localhost (11.213.234.24) on port 9200 from vagrant

Tags: centos, vagrant, elasticsearch

I am running vagrant from a virtual box with centos. Trying to connect my localhost on port 9200 from vagrant by using (curl -X GET 'http://11.213.234.24:9200'). Getting below error

```
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

Also I have added the `config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "11.213.234.24"` in vagrant file

I have been trying with in browser `http://11.213.234.24:9200/` , i could see the results

```
{
  "name" : "qAn6D9F",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "cluster_uuid" : "XH_d3889RPChpcY261vLRQ",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "5.5.3",
    "build_hash" : "9305a5e",
    "build_date" : "2017-09-07T15:56:59.599Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "6.6.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Does anyone know what the issue could be?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a forwared port from localhost to guest machine, it has to work for sure:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 9200, host: 9200
end
```

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:9200
```

When using public network configuration a bridge interface with host machine ethernet adapter will be added, and you need to set up IP address from the same subnet.

See https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/ for more details.